# Retornar a diferença entre os dois últimos registros

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

O que eu preciso fazer está nessa imagem. Como eu faço?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a query que fiz e está vindo vazia e não sei porque.

```
SELECT event_type, value from teste t1
Where       exists (select event_type, value
                    from teste t2
                    where t2.event_type = t1.event_type
                    and   t2.value = t1.value
                    group by event_type, value 
                    having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: é só ler, hehe brincadeira, o certo seria você traduzir não acha? :)

Comment: O tempo e por isso eu postei tudo e só tenho 1:20 para terminar e são três perguntas. O que se pede é pegar os valores repetidos fazer uma sub com o primeiro valor e o último.

Comment: Você teria melhor resultado postando no SO em inglês, visto que não pode traduzir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No SQL Server podes fazer da seguinte forma

```
;with cte as 
(
    select event_type,
           value,
           [time],
           dense_rank() over (partition by event_type order by [time] desc) rn
    from   [events]
)
select c1.event_type, c1.value - c2.value value
from   cte c1
inner join cte c2
  on c2.event_type = c1.event_type
 and c2.rn = c1.rn + 1
where c2.rn = 2
order by 1
```

Testei com essa tabela e esses dados e produziu o resultado esperado.

Podes verificar o SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4f05/3

Comment: Nome de objeto 'cte2' inválido. Esse é o erro quando eu executo

Comment: Não é nada disso. Vou postar no inglês. O resposta deveria ser: 2 <<< -5 e 3 <<< 4

Comment: Tá vindo vazio o resultado. Fiz uma query com Having e também vem vazia. Vou editar e postar a query. Não sei porque está assim.

Answer (score 1):

No MySql você pode fazer assim:

```
select 
  event_type,
  count_event_type,
  (select value from events events_2 where events_2.event_type = events.event_type order by time desc limit 0,1) -
  (select value from events events_2 where events_2.event_type = events.event_type order by time desc limit 1,1) as total2
from (
    select 
      event_type,
      count(event_type) count_event_type,
      value,
      time
    from 
       events
    group by event_type
  ) events
 having count_event_type > 1;
```

Exemplo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2180e/16

Comment: No Sql Server como eu substituo o limit

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 é o mesmo que o LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta :)

```
select e.event_type,
       e.value - (select top 1 value from events
                  where event_type = e.event_type
                    and time <> e.time
                  order by time desc) as value
from events e
where e.time = (select top 1 time from events
                where event_type = e.event_type
                order by time desc)
order by e.event_type ASC
```

### [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3dfa/3/0)